# Norm of closure and its extreme points

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $H$ be an inﬁnite dimensional separable Hilbert space with orthonormal basis $(e_n)_{n\geq1}$ and let $D$ be the norm closure of $co\{\frac{1}{N}\sum \limits_{n=1}^{N^2}e_N : N ≥ 1\}$.

I want to show that $D$ is weakly compact, and that $0 ∈ D$ as well as to find the extreme points in $D$.

**Guess for some of the extreme points in $D$**: 0, as well as each $\frac{1}{N}\sum \limits_{n=1}^{N^2}e_N, N ≥ 1$,